# What kind of paint should be used on an outdoor concrete walkway?

Tags: painting, concrete, paint, outdoor

I have an outdoor walkway that was freshly painted just before I bought my house two years ago. Two winters have worn down the paint and now it needs another coat or the exposed concrete will crumble.

[image: Outdoor concrete walkway]

I have two goals with re-painting the walkway.

1. **Protect the concrete** (this is a must)
2. **Add a non-slip texture** (this is not necessary, but would be nice to
   have)

To these ends, **what type of paint should I use** that is not slippery in cold, wet winter weather?

For point 2, **is it possible to mix in gritty sand without compromising the paint**? Or should I paint the walkway with some 'concrete safe' paint, then add a non-slip layer on top?

The walkway will need to be shoveled, **will adding a layer of non-slip grit make the paint more prone to chipping**?

Answer (score 2):

Paint on a concrete walkway will never last very long, and adding sand would definitely make it chip faster. The correct way to do it would be to stain it. I would use a [good stain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorative_concrete) instead of what you get at the big box stores. Then seal it. Concrete sealer you can get anywhere. You can add some [sharkgrip](https://www.hcconcrete.com/product/sharkgriptm-slip-resistant-additive/) to it for the non-slip you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your local home center or paint supplier and ask for an exterior concrete floor paint they will have what you need. I wouldn't mix in the grit with the paint, rather I'd sprinkle it on top while the paint is still wet. This is similar to what's done with epoxy coatings.